# How to "fastboot flashing unlock" when device has no volume rocker?

Tags: rom-flashing, fastboot

I have a android tablet that has no volume buttons, but has an unlocked OEM bootloader. I'm trying to flash a new rom, and after I run `fastboot flashing unlock` I am presented with a prompt that asks for me to press volume up.

Is there anyway to override this prompt? like `-y` or something?

I'm asking for a general solution as this problem happens to a lot of people from time-to-time. Whether it be from a broken rocker or from a device that has no volume buttons.

Edit: I didn't think to add the type of tablet, since none of you all would have heard of it. It is an `eewrite e-pad pro by Wisky (sold by novadealshop)` running Android 7.1.1. Any additional information about its specs can be found here: https://www.reddit.com/r/e_pad/comments/drmi5s/full_device_info_for_eewriter_epad_by_wisky/

Comment: `fastboot oem unlock-go`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between fastboot oem unlock and fastboot oem unlock-go?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/226090/what-is-the-difference-between-fastboot-oem-unlock-and-fastboot-oem-unlock-go)

Answer (score 0):

When a device has no volume rocker it is usually flashed using an external tool and not via traditional fastboot methods.

In this case, the device is a MediaTek Android smartphone (MTK based), and nearly every smartphone with this chipset can be flashed not using fastboot, but with the `SP Flash Tool`.

The latest version `SPFlash Tool v5.1924` can be downloaded at:

[spflashtool.com](https://spflashtool.com/) or [androidmtk.com](https://androidmtk.com/smart-phone-flash-tool)

This tool allows the flashing of Scatter Based Stock Firmware on devices powered by Mediatek Chipsets. All you need is the correct Scatter based Stock Firmware of your Device.

Comment: your question is about unlocking bootloader. your answer is about flashing stock ROM. i don't think your answer is solution for headline