# Using a keyboard to send Volume Up signal to confirm flash on device without volume rocker?

Tags: rom-flashing, recovery-mode, fastboot, usb-debugging, usb-c

## Background

I have a tablet that I am trying to fastboot flash a custom ROM on. The problem is this tablet has no volume rocker. In order to flash, fastboot requires you to press volume on the device up to confirm the flash. My question to bypass this is in a [different post](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/218621/10658).

Device is very obscure: An `Eewrite (manufactured by Alps) e-pad pro by Wisky (sold by novadealshop)` bought from Hong Kong, running Android 7.1.1 with a Type-C adapter, a physical home and power button.

## Question

Would it be possible to send the volume up signal using a usb-c splitter/hub and a keyboard that has a volume up button?

I want to ask before I buy the keyboard and thunderbolt-3 hub. I am also worried that many of these hubs might not be recognized by the lowlevel stock recovery environment.

Comment: I see now how my thinking and wording of the problem limited my ability to describe and troubleshoot it. Thank you for the clarifications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fastboot is implemented in bootloader (like [`aboot`](https://lineageos.org/engineering/Qualcomm-Firmware/) or [LK](http://www.lieberbiber.de/2015/07/05/mediatek-details-little-kernel/)) i.e. in boot chain it loads even before the first process (kernel) of main OS. It has its own very minimal kernel which doesn't recognize any hardware components (even on device) except those necessarily required at this stage (processor, memory, display, flash storage etc.). Communication with PC over USB is only acceptable through `fastboot` protocol which doesn't have support to accept keystrokes or other input events (at least I never heard of such functionality). So it won't receive your