# What is the difference between fastboot oem unlock and fastboot oem unlock-go?

Tags: fastboot, command-line, bootloader-lock

I'm having issues unlocking my Nexus 7 2013 WiFi's bootloader, and it was suggested that I try `fastboot oem unlock-go` instead of `fastboot oem unlock`. Both seem to act the same on my device, however both also fail on my device so it is possible that the difference appears after the failure on my end comes.

Regardless, I would like to know: What is the difference between these two commands? I'm not managing to find documentation.

Comment: are both commands available at this device? the only difference i can imagine is for `-go` something is skipped (maybe erasing userdata, or confirmation dialog)? you can tell us

Comment: @alecxs both are available yes, and looking at the log I did not notice anything being skipped, however it ends prematurely due to it always failing (for currently unknown reasons). The confirmation dialogue was still there.

Comment: [This XDA](https://www.xda-developers.com/how-to-discover-hidden-fastboot-commands/) post says 1.it is specific to OEM 2. How to see if it this command is honored by your device 3.warns you not to try running fastboot commands of this type

Comment: @beeshyams this link is not helpful, the only explained command is oem off-mode-charge

Comment: @alecxs It is helpful to the extent *not* to try that command, if the device doesn't support and how to determine that. I didn't attempt to answer but provided what I found

Comment: @beeshyams thx for this. but it is misleading and contradictory to warn that `fastboot oem unlock-go` differs in any way from `fastboot flashing unlock` and therefore shouldn't be tried

Comment: @alecxs the point is OP doesn't know and I don't know the difference between these commands and you would agree it's not a good idea to run such commands without understanding the outcome. I was only emphasising this, while `fastboot flashing unlock` is known and well understood. I am as keen to know what the difference is and when does one use this? That's why up voted question

Comment: @beeshyams `-go` is recommended as alias on every 2nd tutorial, but nobody knows the difference. have seen this for by-passing xiaomi bootloader lock (**temporary** unlock?) http://xiaomitips.com/guide/unlock-redmi-note-3-bootloader-without-official-permission

Comment: @alecxs I too saw similar but IDK if it is an alias or two distinct things. Maybe it is a temporary unlock?

Comment: `fastboot oem ...` commands aren't standardized by Google. They are vendor specific. As a rough guess, they'd be 50+ from different vendors I have come across. Vendors even implement their own non-`oem` commands in `fastboot`, not following Google's recommendations. Because technically speaking bootloader (which includes `fastboot`) is not a part of Android. Usually OEMs don't provide official documentation on their fastboot implementation. So what the community knows is mostly based on reverse engineering flashing tools (which sometimes are plain batch or shell files).

Answer (score 4):

Most device will prompt an Yes/No UI, and the user can press Volume Up/Down to choose an option, and press power to comfirm.

"fastboot oem unlock-go" will skip the prompt. But no all device support this command.

Comment: thx for clarifying :)

Comment: Can you help me find the documentation for this? I can't find `fastboot oem unlock-go` anywhere.