# How to press power button using fastboot command?

Tags: fastboot, bootloader, oneplus-6

I want to unlock my Oneplus 6 bootloader. But my power button is not working, so at the screen where I have to select, 'unlock the bootloader' I don't know how to do it without Power button??

Hope u could help me..

Comment: What actions have you performed so far or which tutorial for unlocking to you use?

Comment: fix power button before unlock

Comment: Ik that fixing the power button would help me.... But I want to know is there any fastboot command to simulate power button click?

Comment: there is no such command because that device is shipped with physical button from stock, why should it have simulation for? *'fastboot oem key 5'* = is power button on some devices with no physical button only. fastboot [oem](https://www.xda-developers.com/how-to-discover-hidden-fastboot-commands) commands are device specific and not standardized. if no custom command is available you should fix power button before unlock

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between fastboot oem unlock and fastboot oem unlock-go?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/226090/what-is-the-difference-between-fastboot-oem-unlock-and-fastboot-oem-unlock-go)

Comment: None of the suggested methods helped me :( I think the only option is to get my power button fixed.